# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS to 20.04.1 LTS using downloaded iso

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

Where can I find instructions on how to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS to 20.04.1 LTS **using the downloaded iso?**

My internet connection is very slow (dial-up) so I need to upgrade using the iso.

I'm not sure why this isn't an option to choose from since they recommend upgrading from one LTS to another LTS.1 release (or am I missing something).

Comment: @user535733 the only options it gives is to erase or install alongside the 18.04 install.  I'm trying to upgrade in-place.

Comment: They are having issues
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/08/ubuntu-20-04-upgrade-notification-delay

Comment: More info
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1891680?_ga=2.39988711.458318618.1599403715-836305745.1599403715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a full upgrade over dial up took about 7 hours.

The link below may be helpful because doing this will cause timeouts and could cause corruption in some files and this fixed it.

[Fix Broken Ubuntu OS Without Reinstalling It](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/)
First of all, try to login with live cd and backup your data in an external drive. Just in case, if this method didn't work, you can still have your data and reinstall everything!

At the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to **tty1**.

Now, type the following commands one by one to fix the broken Ubuntu Linux.

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Finally, reboot the system using command:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

I Also ran into this
[How To Fix Busybox Initramfs Error On Ubuntu](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-busybox-initramfs-error-on-ubuntu/)